# Laravel 5.4: Unable to customise reset password validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I override the default validation for resetting passwords in Laravel's auth scaffolding?

I've copied the following methods from the ResetsPasswords trait and into my ResetPasswordController:

```
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

If I remove a rule e.g. 'min:6' error messages are still returned when using a password which is less than 6 characters in length.

I've reffered to the relevant documentation,but I haven't been able to take it what I need from it.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is coming from validation, since you are using `$this->validate` method you don't have full control of validation process.

Usually, overwriting validation rules in `ResetPasswordController` would have resolved the issue.

Here is another way, let's use `Validator` class directly so we can have full control in `Auth\ResetPasswordController`

```
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $validator = validator($request->all(), [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ], $this->validationErrorMessages());

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        //do stuffs here like
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    //if we get here means validation passed :) so lets allow these to continue

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    if($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET)
    {
        //means password reset was successful
        return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
    }else{
        //means reset failed
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only('email'))
            ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
}
```

NB: Ensure you are using the right route
You could use:

```
Route::post('/reset-password', [
    'uses'=>'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset',
    'as' => 'reset'
]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I've tested the above and the form still seems to return errors from validation rules which I have removed, the reponse variable seems to be the cause of this.